# Issu with loop and df

Tags: loops, dataframe

I have an issue with a loop and dataframe.

I have a list of files named list_files(folder)=['c://...//X1.txt',...'c://...//X36.txt']
I want to import in df all of them naming them d1, d2,...d36. My code seems right (I have no error) but it fails to create my di.

My code is :

```
len(list_files(folder))
Range=list(range(0,len(list_files(folder))))
Range
```

Range is equal to [0,1,2,...,36]

```
for i in Range :
   j=list_files(folder)[i] 
   di=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(j, sep = ",",header=0, index_col=0,parse_dates=True, encoding=None, tupleize_cols=False, infer_datetime_format=False)
```

### When I try to see a di, I have this message :

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 d1

NameError: name 'd1' is not defined"

I hope someone can help me :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to the same variable `di` every time.

You're expecting R to interpret `di` as standing for `d1, d2, ...` depending on the value of `i`, but why would it do that?

Use a list or vector named `d` instead.